# How to get TCITEM structure of a tab item?

Tags: c, winapi, tabs

I have created a tab control and some tab items on it. At some point, I have to reset the tab item text. Of course, I can always use the following to do this:

```
TCITEM tie;
tie.mask = TCIF_TEXT | TCIF_IMAGE;
tie.iImage = -1;
tie.pszText = _T("Start Page");
SendMessage(panel->hwndTab, TCM_SETITEM, tabIndex, (LPARAM)&tie);
```

But I wonder if we can get the TCITEM structure of a tab item, and we just reset the psztext member of this TCITEM? Can we get the TCITEM structure of a tab item by sending `TCM_GETITEM` message?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're suggesting then no, I don't think there would be any benefit to calling `TCM_GETITEM` first to fill out a `TCITEM` structure.

Calling `TCM_GETITEM` will give you a *copy* of the information contained in the item, so simply changing the string that `pszText` points to will do nothing until you call `TCM_SETITEM` and pass in the new value.

Since you already know what value you want to set, there is no point in getting the current value first, just keep doing what you're doing.

I'm not sure if you are intentionally setting the image as well, but if you don't want to do that you can remove the `TCIF_IMAGE` flag, and skip setting the `iImage` parameter.

Comment: my question is: Suppose the first time(when I created the tab item), I set `tie.iImage = -1`; Then later, I want to reset the tab item text, but keep `tie.iImage` as before. So if I don't specify `tie.iImage = -1` this time, I just write `tie.pszText = _T("Start Page");`, then does `tie.iImage` is changed from `-1` to
`0`? If this is the case, each time I have to give the complete information and this is the reason I wonder if we can get the complete information first, modify it then call `TCM_SETITEM`.

Comment: That's what the mask field in the TCITEM structure is for. It tells the TCM_SETITEM call which things you want to change and which things you want to leave alone.